# Finding a substring

Tags: c, substring

I have to write some code for an assignment which finds a substring within a string.

Here is my code, and I added comments:

```
// the target is the substring that we want to find in the source string
// m is the length of the target, and n is the length of the source
int contains(char target[], int m, char source[], int n) {
int flag = 0; // the source originally does not contain the target
int i;

    // go through each character of the source string
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int targetIndex = 0;
    int j;

            // check if the preceding characters of the source string are a substring
            // that matches the target string
    for(j = i; j < n && targetIndex < m; j++) {
        if(target[targetIndex] == source[j]) {
            flag = 1;
            targetIndex += 1;
        }
        else {
            flag = 0; // a letter does not match
            break;
        }
    }
}

return flag;
```

}

So when I test this method, I always get `0` returned and I can't understand why.
If I try `int i = contains("potatoes", 8, "toes", 4);` it gives `0`.
I've tried putting some print statements to see what character it matches, and it seems it only finds the first letter `"t"`.

Comment: Since this is basically just `strstr()`, I suggest you have a look at an implementation, e. g. the one in glibc.

Comment: Do you want to correct this code? or wants better way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the outer `for` when you have a match.

The way your code works, you may find a match, then run the outer loop again and "forget" about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int targetIndex = 0;
    int j;

            // check if the preceding characters of the source string are a substring
            // that matches the target string
    for(j = i; j < n && targetIndex < m; j++) {
        if(target[targetIndex] == source[j]) {
            flag = 1;
            targetIndex += 1;
        }
        else {
            flag = 0; // a letter does not match
            break;
        }
    }
  if(flag == 1)  
  {
   break;
  }
}
```

You can instead try with the **[strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)** function of C which will make things easier for you.

Example:

```
char *x= "Find the substring in this string";
char *y= "substring";
if(strstr(x, y) != NULL) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you outer `break;` is unconditional

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:- Thanks Grijesh for pointing that. Updated my answer. But I think the second option is more better which OP must adopt!

Comment: now it is good but actaully you don't need `else{..}` in inner for loop just set `flag = 0` before outer break loop, Additionally don't use `break` instead `return i;` at outer if.

Comment: One more point you don't need extra flag variable just check whether `j > i + m` in if in outer for loop... Actually the code written by OP can improve much better.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to your code with explanatory comments.

```
// the target is the substring that we want to find in the source string
// m is the length of the target, and n is the length of the source
int contains(char target[], int m, char source[], int n) {
int flag = 0; // the source originally does not contain the target
int i;

    // go through each character of the source string
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int targetIndex = 0;
    int j;

            // check if the preceding characters of the source string are a substring
            // that matches the target string
    for(j = i; j < n && targetIndex < m; j++) {
        if(target[targetIndex] == source[j]) {
            targetIndex += 1;
            if(targetIndex == m) { // the 'target' has been fully found
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)  // 'target' is already found, no need to search further
    {
      break;
    }
}

return flag;
}
```

Break both the inner and outer loop when the substring is fully found.

EDITED:
Also, instead of `int i = contains("potatoes", 8, "toes", 4);` , it should be `int i = contains("toes", 4, "potatoes", 8);` -- as per your function description.